# class loading when open a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I was doing a simple class that change value of a dom element but I got an error
[image: Problem]

```
class GennerCaptcha{
    constructor(){
        document.getElementById('w').innerHTML((Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7));
    }
}

var b= new GennerCaptcha();
```

Comment: 1. One can't see the error (it's cut off).    2. Never post images of code or errors. Is there any other error (e.g. console)? What's the expected and real behaviour? See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is not a method but a field, change by

`.innerHTML=(Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);`

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
document.getElementById('w').innerHTML=(Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
```